# How to parse an external json file in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

I want to parse an external JSON file into my react app.

Here, I created a working example of what I want in Codesandbox.io:

https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-tdd-we2v3?file=/src/App.js

In this example, I am using some JSON data inside of the application but wanted to parse this data from an outside source file here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Forschung/AmbeentData/main/modems.json

I tried some ways but could be successful.

Best

Comment: Consider using `fetch`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API --- _"I tried some ways but could be successful."_ please edit the question and show those efforts?

Comment: I tried that, but it seems no luck for me :/

Comment: Share that effort as an [mcve]. _"no luck for me"_ is not helpful.

Comment: I already did, please click the first link and you will see that. And the problem solved by @milad-reisi

Comment: Links to offsite resources are not helpful when describing he problem. Please include everything you can in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'json file is wrong' the correct one should be

> "key": "value"

You did this as

> key: "value"

***Wrong Json file***

```
[
    { Brand:"Actiontec", Model:"GT784WNV" },
    { Brand:"Actiontec", Model:"MI424WR" },
    { Brand:"AirTies", Model:"Air 4450" }
]
```

***Must Have Json File***

```
[
   {
      "Brand":"Actiontec",
      "Model":"GT784WNV"
   },
   {
      "Brand":"Actiontec",
      "Model":"MI424WR"
   },
   {
      "Brand":"AirTies",
      "Model":"Air 4450"
   }
]
```

The answer to the second question is that you can make this request very simply using the axios library. I'll leave the sample code and the live example.

[Proje Test Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-golick-2vvcu?file=/src/App.js:229-532)

***Sample code***

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios(
      "json link"
    )
      .then((res) => setDatas(res.data))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e))
      .finally(() => console.log('finally'));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON data format is invalid and that the reason for this problem.
you can fetch data as pure text and then fix them locally like this.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-forest-35oyb?file=/src/App.js)

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
async function getData() {
  fetch(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Forschung/AmbeentData/main/modems.json"
  )
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function (txt) {
      let d = txt.replace(/Brand/g, `"Brand"`);
      d = d.replace(/Model/g, `"Model"`);
      d = JSON.parse(d);
      setData(d);
    });
}
getData();
}, []);
```